# Titan: Elastic search sorting based on edge datatype

Tags: titan

I have below java client ElasticSearch code

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
.setTypes("vertex")
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("  4y:IN AND 4O:samsung")).addSort("???", SortOrder.DESC)
.setFrom((start-1)*2).setSize(2)
.execute()
.actionGet();
```

Its working well. Here `4y` `4O` are the encoded vertex property name.

below is the titan indexing

```
TitanKey time = g.makeKey("time").dataType(Long.class).make();
g.makeLabel("created").sortKey(time).sortOrder(Order.DESC).make();
```

Now in the ES code what should i add to `addSort()` to get sorted result based on `time`? any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

First off, in order to exploit time as a sort order in ES you need to also index it:

```
g.makeKey("time").dataType(Long.class).indexed("search",Vertex.class).make();
```

Secondly, why don't you use Titan's query engine for this query? It seems that this would make your live a lot easier:

```
g.query().has("part",CONTAINS,"IN").has("name",CONTAINS,"Samsung").orderBy("time",Order.DESC).vertices()
```